# Extract, delete any number within braces

Tags: excel, vba

Given a string, which may end with a number within braces, how can I extract as separate variables: (1) the number; (2) the string, sans the braces and number?

String examples: `filename.docx` `file name.pdf{10}`

Comment: remove the end brace with replace and split on the opening brace.

Comment: You might consider providing some samples of the types of strings you're working with.  Seems like a good job for regular expressions  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```vb
Filename = "filename.docx" 
Filename = "file name.pdf{10}"

FileNumber = Val(Mid(Filename, InStr(Filename, "{") + 1))
FileText = Split(Filename, "{")(0)
```